# How to remove the separator between the header and the first row in a grouped tableView

Tags: ios, swift, tableview

I am creating a static tableView. My goal is to have a single view that displays a tableView with 3 rows (get support, send feedback, participation terms), and a header + footer.

Right now, it all works fine EXCEPT the fact that there are two extra separators (one between the header and the first cell and the other between the last cell and the footer) that I cannot seem to get rid of.

**Here is my code:**

```
final class viewController: UITableViewController {

    private let headerContainer = UIView()
    private let footerContainer = UIView()

    private let tableData = ["Get Support", "Send Feedback", "Participation Terms"]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        setupHeaderAndFooter()
        setupTableView()
    }

    func setupHeaderAndFooter() {
        /* setup code here (not relevant to this question) */

    func setupTableView() {
        // reinitializing tableView so that we can change its style to grouped
       tableView = UITableView(frame: CGRect.zero, style: .grouped)
       tableView.delegate = self
       tableView.separatorStyle = .singleLine
    }

    //MARK: UITableView Methods

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
        return headerContainer
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
         return 150
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForFooterInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
        return footerContainer
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForFooterInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 200
    }

    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return tableData.count
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return 70
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = UITableViewCell(style: .subtitle, reuseIdentifier: "cell")
        cell.textLabel!.text = tableData[indexPath.row]
        return cell
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post a photo of the result you're getting, and perhaps the result you're expecting?

Comment: Yes, give me one minute

Comment: I have just updated the post with pictures

Comment: You got the answer below :)

Answer (score 0):

One way to achieve this is don't use default separator provided by `UITableView`. and place one `UILabel` or `UIView` and set its background color to light gray and set its height=1 (As per your requirement), width (full tableview width or as per your requirement) and position at bottom of all you content inside cell, header or footer.

Comment: Hey Dhaval, thanks for the answer. The problem with this method is that I would have to create another class for custom tableView cells. I am planning to keep the default cells provided by the `UITableViewController` class. Is there any other work around?

Answer (score -2):

Ok here you go.

The easy trick is actually a one-liner and a self-explanatory:

```
self.tableView.separatorColor = self.tableView.backgroundColor
```

**AFTER:**

[image]

I hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for the answer Glenn. I can see what you are doing there but I probably should have mentioned that I have a background color set for the app. That color is white, so if I set the separator color to the background color of the tableView, I will end up with all the separators not showing up at all! I initially omitted that section of code because I thought it would be irrelevant

Comment: Do you get it that the separator color is equals to the background color of the tableView? So it means that you'll get same result regardless of the color you set to the tableView. So can also make it clear color. ```self.tableView.separatorColor = .clear``` This should solve your issue :)

Comment: Oh yeah, but that way I think that I would be getting rid of all my separators, whereas I only want to get rid of the separators in my header and footer

Comment: In that case, replace your tableView's separatorStyle to none, like so: ```self.tableView.separatorStyle = .none```. Also, don't forget to select an answer to this question to close it.

Comment: I think there's a misunderstanding. I DO want separators between cells. I just DON'T want the separator between the header and the first cell, and the separator between the last cell and the footer. My question is about getting rid of those 2 separators specifically, while keeping every other separator. So far, none of the answers have addresses that, but I will select one as soon as the problem is solved!

Answer (score -2):

You have to set `clipsToBounds` to `true` on your header view.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    let header = //Get your header here
    header.clipsToBounds = true
    return header
}
```

Before:

[image]

After:

[image]